# Test for significant change of means in application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I did a change on my webpage on a given date.
Now a want to measure if there is a significant impact on the usage due to the change. How can I do a sampled t-test in Application Insights? Splitting the time series data on a given date than comparing the two sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the KQL there is a built-in function for calculating Welch's t-test: [welch_test()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/welch-testfunction).

Given a table T with a metric m and a change date d, you can calculate the test by aggregating the metric before and after the change:

```
T
| summarize m1 = avgif(m, Timestamp < d), 
    v1 = varianceif(m, Timestamp < d), 
    c1 = countif(Timestamp < d), 
    m2 = avgif(m, Timestamp > d), 
    v2 = varianceif(m, Timestamp > d), 
    c2 = countif(Timestamp > d)
| extend pValue=welch_test(m1,v1,c1,m2,v2,c2)
```

Comment: Thank you, works great!
I wish AutoComplete / Intellisense had worked for these *if - functions as well...